# Cannot find deobfuscation file upload in new google paly console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, deobfuscation

For some reason, I cannot find the page in the new Google play console where I used to upload deobfuscation files for android applications.

If you know where to find it, please let us know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also had issues finding the section to upload the deobfuscation file. I was able to find it, following the simple (but sort of hidden) steps below:

- Create a new release, in the new release dashboard
- Upload the bundle or APK
- Once successfully uploaded, you should see the summary of the new release below, click the kebab menu button to the far right (see screenshot)
- Click "Upload ReTrace mapping file (.txt or .map)" and upload your deobfuscation file
- Also, similar to the old play console, you can upload the deobfuscation file later (after releasing) by going back to the release dashboard and following these steps

[image: deobfuscation upload menu screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Not sure why google decided to hide this feature :-(